# Why I cannot override the Clear method of a generic class?

Tags: delphi, generics

I have a class

```
TMonitors = class(System.Generics.Collections.TList<TMonitor>)
```

I populate it with `TMonitor` objects. When I call `TMonitors.Clear` I want to free those objects, so naturally I want to override the `Clear` method. However, `Clear` is not virtual. Instead is declared as "inline" so I get a "Cannot override a non-virtual method" from the compiler.

My question is actually why is `Clear` not virtual (or dynamic) as in the "normal" `TList`? What is the correct approach to "override" it in this case?

Comment: Just use a [`TObjectList<T>`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Generics_Collections_TObjectList.html). It will take care of freeing your objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct approach is to use a different structure.  `TList` inlines `Clear`, presumably for performance, and this [precludes it being `virtual`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/E2425_Inline_methods_must_not_be_virtual_nor_dynamic_(Delphi)).  [`TObjectList`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectList_(Delphi)) is provided, however, for cases where you require the list to take responsibility for object lifetime, so use that instead.

Comment: +1 and accepted. But what if in the list I have not objects but pointers to records for which I need to de-allocate the memory with Dispose?

Comment: Good question in that comment, but not the one you asked here. We could answer it if you asked it.

Comment: @Migrate2Lazarusseemyprofile Agreed, that's a completely separate question.  My first temptation would be to seriously reconsider such a tedious design.